# Add license agreement to setup project as embeded resource?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, setup-project

I'm trying to add a licence.rtf file to my setup project, I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182364/how-to-add-licence-agreement-in-the-setup-project) stackoverflow answer step by step in order to add the licence file.

What seems to be happening is when I add the license file it doesn't add it as an embeded resource so when I remove the file from my local machine i get a complie time error...I also do not see any property which let's me change the license file to an embeded resource.

This is the error that I'm getting
[image: The error im getting]

Please let me know if anyone has experienced this issue before and how can I go about fixing it

**UPDATE:**

When you add the licence.rtf file to the Setup Project it **does not** have a BuildAction property which can be set to EmbededResource.Tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have figured it out. Instead of trying to add the License.rtf file to the setup project I've added it to another project in the solution.

Once done I reference ***that*** file in my setup project and when the setup file get's compiled the license file is embeded in the exe.

Answer (score 0):

Click the file in solution explorer, view properties. Then change Build Action to Embedded Resource.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to show a license agreement in a Visual Studio setup project is as follows:

1. Go to the User Interface view in the IDE. Right-click "Start" and then Add Dialog, add the License Agreement dialog.
2. Right click the dialog to move it up or down. Right-click and Properties Windows shows properties where under License you can browse for your custom license RTF file.