# Visual studio 2015: License agreement dialog

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am doing windows desk app in visual studio app. I need to deploy it now.

My question is:
 
How to do the license agreement dialog during setting up when setup run?

I read the post here: [How to add Licence agreement in the setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182364/how-to-add-licence-agreement-in-the-setup-project). 
But I cannot follow the same steps in visual studio 2015.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Protip: when your screenshot contains 60% whitespace, *crop it*.

Comment: What purpose does the image serve that couldn't be shown as text? If you felt you absolutely had to include an image, why does it have so much blank white space instead of being cropped to only what was necessary? Images should only be used to demonstrate things that cannot be explained any other way, and should be as small as possible if they're absolutely needed. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons you should *not* post images.

Comment: @KenWhite well explaned!

Comment: Any hints about my problems? Thanks

Comment: Why you cannot follow steps provided in that article? Please explain.

Comment: @Alex I cannot  find the license agreement dialogthe answer mentioned

Comment: @BAE do you have  "a setup project"?

Comment: I had to read through the edit history of your question to see what you are doing. If you want a full setup program with all the features, you need to create a setup project. The classic setup project can be downloaded as an extension from here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9. This may help also: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/301d7b68-914b-4a05-8f2b-d9aa53f69cca/sneaky-way-to-get-an-eula-displayed-for-your-clickonce-application-in-vs2005?forum=winformssetup

Comment: In VS2015, the License Agreement is in under Customize The Setup Appearance -> Dialogs.

Comment: @Alex Thanks... I will try