# Adding 'User Interface' including license agreement in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

For publishing a .NET desktop application, I would like to add a **user interface** that includes a license agreement during installation. I searched through some of the [contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182364/how-to-add-licence-agreement-in-the-setup-project) but couldn't find it for Visual Studio Community 2022. In the solution, there is no **View** menu. Can you let me know how to add the license agreement and other pages during installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out my nanny-level teaching！

Environment：

[image]

1. Add extention

[image]

2. Install Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project

[image]

3. Closs the ide to start installing:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

4. Create a setup project:

[image]
[image]

5. Right-click on the "Start" group, and select "Add Dialog" from the pop-up menu.

[image]

6. n the "Add Dialog" dialog, click the "License Agreement" icon and click "OK". A license agreement form will be added to your installer under the "Start" group.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Jiale_Xue Thank you for sharing. I found your approach is creating a new project for setup. If so, how do I integrate with the main project?

Comment: You could refer these links. [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022#create-a-setup-project) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/wx3b589t(v=vs.100)).